# Changing the mobile website url to main website

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

have a good day.

Actually I'm creating a mobile website and and I've uploaded to it's domain like(www.example.com/mobile). But I'm facing a problem is that when I access the site through mobile it shows the whole URL to the folder where the site exists. But I want it to show the same address like (www.example.com).

The code I've used to redirect to mobile site is available on this site...

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com

Anyone can please tell me how can i do this...?

Thank you so much for helping me...

Comment: AFAIK, this can only be done by server-side code.  What language are you using on the server?  (PHP, ASP.Net etc).

Comment: sorry for late.. ya php

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php